# Filter regex not valid

Tags: java, regex

i have a problem with text pattern in java. I want to use this pattern to validate inserted text to filter text in table. This text can contain "!"(not) and "*"(like?). I have also possibility to use & (and) and |(or) to join logical expressions together with text operations (endsWith, startsWith, contains). What exactly i want is to avoid inserting not validate text. Examples for not valid text

```
-
!
!*
*!
!!
**
*!
!*
A**
**A
*A&
&A*
```

And examples for valid text

```
A*
*A
*-*
!a|b&c|!ab
!a|*b&c*|!*ab
!*aa*|*sdb&casd*|!*aasdb*
!*aa|*sdb&casd*|!*aasdb*
S*|L*
```

With my pattern `"\s*(!?\*?[^&\|]*[&\|])*!?\*?[^&\|]*\*?\s*"` both groups are valid. I tried difference combinations but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: why the first input is not valid and why the second is valid?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen this is not .gitignore file.

Comment: @YCF_L based on my pattern both inputs are valid but i want to create pattern which make, that the first input will be invalid and the second stay valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of what you wan't, and your examples aren't absolutely clear. For example, `*-*` is valid indicating `-` is a valid filter character, so why is just a `-` invalid? That's not logical.

But from what I can gather, you're after something like this:

```
\s*(?:!?\*?[^&|*!\n]+\*?[&|])*!?\*?[^&|*!\n]+\*?\s*
```

It uses a non capturing group for the first, optional part. If this is present it ends with a `|` or a `&`. Then follows the non optional part, which is the same, except for not having the terminating operator:

An optional `!`, possibly followed by an optional `*`. Then any character **but** a `&`, `|`, `!` or newline - at least one. Finally an optional `*` can follow.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tKneq1/1).

Note that not anchoring to start and end (`^` and `$`) implies using java's `matches` method, that does that for you. Using another method, or another regex flavor, will require those to be added, or this will match basically anything.

Comment: QClasG you are are right about "-". This "-" should also be valid.

THis pattern is what i am looking for :)